# Adding Prioritization To a Thread Without Busy Waiting in C (Linux)

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, synchronization, thread-priority

I have a prioritization problem in my homework. Some threads have higher priorities than the others and the other threads have to wait to access a file until all those threads have finished their job. We are not allowed to use busy waiting. Is there another solution to solve this. Thanks.

Comment: This is a bit messy.  A synchro object to manage that would need control of all the low-priority threads before any of the high-priority threads are started.  It would need to know the number of  high-priority threads.  The high-priority threads would have to  call in to the object when finished with the file.  Could be done....

Comment: My first thought is a struct with a mutex, (to protect its internal data), an initialized total number of high and low threads, a count of high threads that have finished with the file and a semapbore upon which the low threads must wait before starting with the file.

Comment: This would be much easier with an OO language:)

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, OK, like my comment.

The low-priority threads must wait on the, (initialized to zero), semaphore before accessing the file.  The high-priority threads, when they have finished with tbe file, must acquire the mutex, count down the high count check for zero and release the mutex.  The last high-thread that finds zero should then issue [low count] units to the semaphore, so releasing all the low threads.

Actually, a mutex-protected struct with state data can handle just about any weird locking/sequencing/prioritizing scheme that your prof can come up with, no matter how much tequila it consumes first:)